# Developing iOS app with Phonegap *entirely* on Ubuntu?

Tags: cordova

Is it possible? or would I need a Mac at some stage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a Mac to submit your app to AppStore if you want it to appear there, but of course, you can always sell it on Cydia.

Comment: Would an iPhone device be sufficient or is it really a Mac that I need in order to submit to the AppStore?

Comment: @shaharsol you will need a Mac to submit it, and 99 dollars to join the program which let you submit it.

Answer (score 2):

According to the FAQ for [Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) you should be able to upload your project to the build service and get an app-store ready app for iOS.

It's still in beta and I haven't tried it myself. To debug on Ubuntu I guess you could run it as a android project and hope there isn't to much difference between the platforms...

I'm not sure if you would need an actual Mac to submit the app to app-store.

Answer (score 2):

PhoneGap Build will let you build for iOS and you can sign your iOS developer certificates without a Mac. See: [Create iOS Distribution Certificate windows - Apple provisioning Portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233131/create-ios-distribution-certificate-windows-apple-provisioning-portal)

Only part you MUST have a Mac for is for submitting to AppStore using Application Loader. Check out http://macincloud.com which let's you pay by the hour for using a Mac with Application Loader preinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop application but you can not deploy it for ios devices. You need an xcode installation to do this.