# Create iOS Distribution Certificate windows - Apple provisioning Portal

Tags: ios, air, portal

I am a droid developer using as3 air for android using a PC. I just purchased an apple account to export for iphones. However I am stuck on the provisioning portal that apple makes. How can I create one of these keys without buying a mac?

I included an image shot of my screen.

I try to upload some provisioning files but it just refreshes with no warning of what went wrong. Just goes blank.

Thanks for your help!

[image: Wish Apple did not make like so complicated.]

Comment: check the AIR documentation... do they allow you to build signed iOS apps via PC's?  I didn't think that was possible.

Comment: Yes using flash professional you can export now an ios version.

Answer (score 13):

To create a distribution cert in Windows:

1 - `call openssl genrsa -out ios_distribution.key 2048`

2 - `call openssl req -new -key ios_distribution.key -out CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest -subj "/emailAddress=%YOUR_EMAIL%, CN=%YOUR_NAME%, C=%YOUR_COUNTRY_CODE_EG_US%"`

3 - Upload the newly created CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest at: https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/distribute.action

** Note if your certSigningRequest is the wrong format or you try to upload the wrong file, the developer.apple.com page will simply refresh with no error message just as you saw. I believe this happens on both Windows and Mac.

4 - Download ios_distribution.cer from developer.apple.com

5 - Create and download YourApp_AppStore.mobileprovision at developer.apple.com using the new certificate and your app

6 - `call openssl x509 -in ios_distribution.cer -inform DER -out ios_distribution.pem -outform PEM`

7 - `call openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey ios_distribution.key -in ios_distribution.pem -out ios_distribution.p12 -passout pass:%YOUR_PASSWORD%`

8 - `call adt -package -target ipa-app-store -storetype pkcs12 -keystore "ios_distribution.p12" -storepass %YOUR_PASSWORD% -provisioning-profile YourApp_AppStore.mobileprovision "fileForAppstore.ipa" "application.xml" -C bin .`

9 - Mark your app as Ready to Upload Binary at itunesconnect.apple.com

10 - Upload fileForAppstore.ipa using Application Loader. This is the ONLY step that requires a Mac!

Comment: In 8th step , what stand for "adt" ?

Comment: AIR Developer Tool, the program you run to make IPAs.  https://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fd9.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm very new too all this, and it took me many hours to finally get it working - thought I'd share some of the bumps I had along the way for other inexperienced folk. 
Sarah's method works great (Hi Sarah - I'm a huge fan, BTW) but here's some extra tips that would have shaved hours off how long it took someone green like me:

Download openSSL here:
http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html
I had to download and install Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x64) from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336 before installing openSSL.

After installing C++ THEN openssl, make sure you run ssl as an administrator (right click to get the option) to avoid issues with missing .cnf files.

I ran the commands in step 1 & 2 by running \OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openSSL.exe, and leaving off the "call openSSL" parts of Sarah's code above.

Before step 3, I had to download and install the Intermediate Certificate "Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority", found on the bottom of the first page when requesting a new developer certificate.

Once I'd downloaded the cert and also made and downloaded the provisioning certificate, I copied them into \OpenSSL-Win32\bin (Not sure if this was necessary)

Then I continued to use Sarah's code in openssl (so still excluding the "call openssl" ) until step 7. I did this instead:

```
pkcs12 -export -inkey ios_development.key -in ios_development.pem -out iphone_dev.p12
```

and was then prompted to define the password I would later need to use the .p12 for  generating test-builds (in my case, using Flash Pro on a Win8 machine building for an iOS7 iPad Mini)

I didn't need steps 8 through to 10 as I'm using Flash Pro, and haven't got my app to store stage yet.

I'm sure I've massively oversimplified some of this for most of you, but for novice programmers like me, this additional info would have saved a lot of wasted time.

The whole process of researching the issues I had, getting my itunes and iOS up to date, working out the problems I was having with the Apple Dev site and openSSL took me a whole day - but I've now finally got my test build running on the iOS device. And now, it's Vodka o'clock.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it since I don't own a PC, but check out the following article:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ff0.html#WSfffb011ac560372f284e44b012cd1e700c0-8000

Especially the last paragraphs should help you.